# Deserialize Dictionary<> using DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, datacontractserializer

I need to deserialize Dictionary<> in C#. Since, XmlSerializer cannot be used for generic Dictionary type, I thought of using DataContractSerializer.I had a StreamReader in which the data was to be deserialized, but it showed unmatching overload parameters on using with DataContractSerializer.ReadObject.
My previous code was:

```
        StreamReader isr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(algorithmName + ".conf"));
        configuration.Load(isr);
```

The Load method is defined as:

```
public void Load(StreamReader isr)
{
    DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(the class containing this method));
    XmlDictionaryReader read = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(isr, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
    dcs.ReadObject(isr);

}
```

The Load method is contained in class that implements Dictionary<>
But this showed parameter mismatched error due to StreamReader as parameter for ReadObject().

So, I modified the code as:

```
FileStream isr = File.OpenRead(algorithmName + ".conf");
        configuration.Load(isr);
```

And the Load method as:

```
public void Load(FileStream isr)
{
    DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(the class containing Load method));
    XmlDictionaryReader read = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(isr, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
    dcs.ReadObject(isr);

}
```

Now there are no errors but I wanted to know whether using DataContractSerializer in place of XmlSerializer is correct or not. Also, any updates on replacing streamreader with filestream would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to keep using XmlSerializer: https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/one-way-to-serialize-dictionaries/ Or think about using Newtonsoft.Json, it supports json to xml and is really easy to use! Here is an example: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/convertingjsonandxml.htm and using serialization/deserialization is really easy with Json.net, so I'd go for it if youre allowed to have extra dependencies

Comment: Imho use json      String serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj); is all u gotta do lol.

Comment: 1) Since your code works, what is your question?  stackoverflow is for specific how-to questions.  Broad questions like "is this the best way to do X" when X is already working are not a good fit here. 2) What do you mean by *any updates on replacing streamreader with filestream would be highly appreciated.*?  Are you looking for [`DataContractSerializer.ReadObject Method (Stream)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574047(v=vs.110).aspx)?